# How do you use git-cache-meta?

Tags: git, metadata, file-permissions

I want keep directories' permissions in a git repository. It seems that one easy way is using `git-cache-meta`. What is an example and a minimal explanation of its use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're referring to [this](https://gist.github.com/andris9/1978266) implementation of `git-cache-meta`, then all you need to do is make sure the script is in your $PATH (put it in `/usr/local/bin/` or similar) and go to repo you want, then run:

```
$ git-cache-meta --store
```

That will store the meta data in a file named `.git_cache_meta` in the rep. Then on another instance of the repo, run:

```
$ git-cache-meta --apply
```