# Git: Track permission change 777 to 444

Tags: git, unix, file-permissions

I have used chmod to change permissions on a file. This file is in my Git repository. I changed it from 777 to 444. Git does not show any changes to the file. How do I add this change to Git?

Using Git verion 1.7.9.5

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git) anwser

Comment: That solution may work, but seems more painful than the answer I accepted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the file from your repository and replace it with the file that you changed.

Comment: Feels hacky but is probably simpler than the solution in the related post pointed out by Lawrence Benson in the comment on my question.

Comment: @sheldonkreger Jacky a bit but probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I copied the file over to a different file name, then used git rm on the original file. Created a git commit for the delete. Then I changed the perms on the duplicate file and moved it back to the original file name. Added it in git, made a commit. That did it.

Answer (score 1):

Git will only track whether the executable bit has changed. So, if you had a file that was `666` and changed it to `777`, git would track this change, but otherwise does not track file permissions. If you need to track permissions with git, this will require third-party tools. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3211396/145279) explains it a bit. You'd need a third-party tool like [git-cache-meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275000/how-do-you-use-git-cache-meta).

Answer (score 1):

from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:unix_file_permissions

> The Wrapper task adds appropriate file permissions to allow the
>   execution of the gradlew *NIX command. Subversion preserves this file
>   permission. We are not sure how other version control systems deal
>   with this. What should always work is to execute “sh gradlew”

.